# issue with ssh into lxd container using ansible

Tags: ssh, lxc, lxd, ansible

I have created a dynamic inventory which fetch the created lxd containers  (so that I don have to type the name of container each time)
so here is the dynamic inventory

```
plugin: community.general.lxd
url: unix:/var/snap/lxd/common/lxd/unix.socket
state: RUNNING
```

here is the output of the inventory

```
ansible-inventory -i lxd.yaml --graph
@all:
  |--@ungrouped:
  |  |--nginx-1
```

I ran ansible -i lxd.yaml -m ping all
and got this output

```
nginx-1 | UNREACHABLE! => {
    "changed": false,
    "msg": "Failed to connect to the host via ssh: root@container-ip: Permission denied (publickey).",
    "unreachable": true
}
```

and ansible.cfg

```
[defaults]
ansible_user = ansible
ansible_become = yes
ansible_lxd_remote = local
ansible_ssh_private_key_file = /home/zakaria/.ssh/id_rsa
```

the problem is that ansible ssh into the container using the root user but I want it to use the ansible user
so how to force ansible to use the ansible user

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you have a ansible.cfg (INI format), and but you used the YAML variable names in your playbook. It is [frustrating](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/issues/36729) that the [names are different](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/9/collections/ansible/builtin/ssh_connection.html#ssh-connection). Here is what your ansible.cfg might look like after the names are fixed:

```ini
[defaults]
remote_user = ansible
ansible_become = yes
private_key_file = /home/zakaria/.ssh/id_rsa
# ansible_lxd_remote (at least the YAML name) is already local by default
```

You clarified that you want to SSH in as the ansible user, then become root later. This is indeed the recommended solution, and you confirmed that the key exists and is set up.

By changing "ansible_user" to "remote_user", we get the "root@container-ip" to turn into the desired "ansible@container-ip". By changing "ansible_ssh_private_key_file" to "private_key_file", we fix the "Permission denied (publickey)" problem. The "ansible_lxd_remote" line was doing nothing. If you have any other variables in your ansible.cfg file, revisit the [linked ssh_connection manual](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/9/collections/ansible/builtin/ssh_connection.html#ssh-connection) and, in the table, find the corresponding "INI entry" names correspond to the (YAML) "Variable" lines.

Comment: I removed the ansible_become but I still has the same issue
I think the lxd's dynamic inventory plugin use root user by default and cannot be overwritten  using the ansible_user variable

Comment: @ZakariaAitYakoub I added another approach

Comment: what is the other approach?

Comment: @ZakariaAitYakoub I added some other lines in the code block, to try other names ending with _user.

Comment: now it show that it ssh using ansible but "Failed to connect to the host via ssh: ansible@container-ip: Permission denied (publickey)."
but I can ssh into the container using ssh ansible@container-ip without any issue

Comment: Are you sure you don't have a `ssh_config` that is making it use a different key file? Does "/home/zakaria/.ssh/id_rsa" exist? You can also add -vvv to the command line to enable debug output.

Comment: yes the /home/zakaria/.ssh/id_rsa exist

Comment: SSH: EXEC ssh -C -o ControlMaster=auto -o ControlPersist=60s -o KbdInteractiveAuthentication=no -o PreferredAuthentications=gssapi-with-mic,gssapi-keyex,hostbased,publickey -o PasswordAuthentication=no -o 'User="ansible"' -o ConnectTimeout=10 -o ControlPath=/root/.ansible/cp/a906f69b2a container-ip '/bin/sh -c '"'"'echo ~ansible && sleep 0'"'"''

Comment: I found a solution in the playbook I need to add the var ansible_ssh_private_key_file, I think there is an issue in the plugin that i dont read the path of the private key in the ansible.cfg, Also I added the become: yes to give sudo privielege to the user

Comment: @ZakariaAitYakoub I found the documentation link that explains this. It is by design and not a bug but it is frustrating. Basically we just need to use the name "private_key_file =". If this helps you move the variable into ansible.cfg and not need to modify the original playbook, please click the "accept answer" button.

Comment: Thanks my dude it worked, I appreciate your help